# Migrating Dll built on .Net v4.0 to .Net Core 1.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, coreclr

I have a dotnet library(dll) that was built on dotnet framework `v4.0`.
Now we want to use that dll in `.Net Core framework 1.0`.

Is this possible that old libraries that were build using previous version of dotnet framework like v4.0 can be directly used in .Net Core 1.0 ?

If yes, then how to do that ?
If no, then what needs to be done in order to support with .Net Core 1.0.

I had gone through various msdn blogs but able to find any solution for console applications. They had lot about ASP.Net core but less in regard for `.Net Core App`.

Comment: This question is to broad to be replied on SO. Please install https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b in your VS 2015 and run it on your 4.0 library and see what apps are incompatible and change/remove/replace them with .NET Core compatible API calls

Comment: @Tseng this really helped. But after installing this extension it do not shows .Net Core in the target platforms list instead it shows ASP.Net Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot directly be used in .NET Core 1.0, but it may be ported.

First thing you should do is test your DLL in the  [**.NET Portability Analyser**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b).

This tool will tell you in a very visual way what methods (and their associated class and namespace) you are using, that are not supported in .NET Core 1.0.

Depending on the feasibility (it's up to you, you know your code), you may choose to try to get rid of this classes/methods and replace them with .NET Core 1.0 compatible code.

**Examples of functionalities not supported in .NET Core 1.0:**

- AppDomains (for code isolation, dynamic assemblies loading)
- Remoting
- Binary serialization

More details on [Core FX github documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/porting.md#unsupported-technologies)

**To attempt to port your dll:**

- get rid of the csproj
- replace it with a project.json (correctly configured to target .NET Core 1.0)
- open the project in visual studio 2015
- try to compile it
- analyse the errors and correct them
- iterate (probably many times :) )

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to directly use a .NET Framework assembly on .NET Core.

There are lots of APIs that aren't available on .NET Core (at least for now). Think for example, Registry API wouldn't make sense for cross-platform

You need to manually port your source code and rebuild it.

There's a new type of library called [.NET standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library), so if you port your source code targeting this, you should be able to run it on .NET Framework and .NET core